# Why the background-image doesn't work in a external CSS but in a internal it does?

Tags: html, css

well, first of all i'm a newbie in HTML and CSS so hope you can understand my lack of knowledge. So, being straight i'm having problems when i try to add a Background-image via external CSS, but weirdly it works in the HTML archive. After that, i was searching about this problem here and i found out a lot of solutions but none of them worked and, mainly, explained why this problem is happening. So, i ask for help, please.
As you can see i even watched out for with add .. in the path when i tried to load by CSS, yet it didn't work.

The whole directory is maked up as bellow:

```
    |part1|
         |css|
             style.css
         |images|
             header_bg.png
             logo.png
         |js|
            there's nothing here till the current moment
         index.html
```

--HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <style type="text/css">
        .container_banner{
            width: 100%;
            height: 557px;
            background-image: url("images/header_bg.png");
        }
    </style> 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="center">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div><!-- close the div center-->
        
    </div><!-- close the header-->
    
    <div class="container_banner">
        <div class="center">
            
        </div><!--close the div center-->
    </div><!--close the container-banner-->
</body>
</html>
```

--My CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.center{
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #212343;
}
 .header img {
    margin: 19px;  
 }

 .container_banner{
    width: 1280px;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url("..images/header_bg.png");
 }
```

Comment: url is incorrect. Try `url("../images/header_bg.png");`

Comment: Wow thanks!! It worked here!!

Answer (score 0):

Any external css stylesheet file will look for images relative to its own URL, if there are relative urls inside it. Example:

http://www.external-website.com/css/style.css contains:

```
background-image: url("images/header_bg.png"); /* This will reference http://www.external-website.com/css/images/header_bg.png */
```

So, if your website's URL is http://my-website.com/ and you're inserting http://www.external-website.com/css/style.css in it, don't expect that relative URLs in that external css file point to http://my-website.com/ resources (in this case, images).

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but my problem was solved...actually i put my path wrong according to Rinkesh Golwala up there...his hint worked out my problem!!

Comment: Another thing...in your explanation about the relatives URLs are you talking about the difference of paths between the external CSS(background-image: url("..images/header_bg.png");) and the HTML document(background-image:url("images/header_bg.png");)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 .container_banner{
    width: 1280px;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url("../images/header_bg.png");
 }
```

/.. is folder in the same way as /images is

Comment: Forgive me Erdien but can you reformulate your question? I didn't understand :)